# read plist file from outside project directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

i have a plist file in my project directory. I can read and write in this plist file.

But is this possible to read plist file from outside project directory?

my code is to read plist file from project dir:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) //mydict is a dictionary type variable
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only read files from your bundle or from one of the other sandboxed directories. You could read/write plist files from your documents directory, for example.

Comment: so if i want to read any plist file from outside project, first i need to add this file to my project than i can read this file. this extra task makes me little bored......... thanks @DuncanC